# python request response seems cut off

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests

I am sending the following request using Python's requests library:

```
files={'file': open(fileURL,'rb')}
r = requests.post(baseUrl + 'api/users/' + userId + apiEndpoint, files=files, headers=headers, stream = True)
r.json()
```

I get the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 15 (char 14)
```

If I try get the content out with `r.content`, I get `b'{"result":true'`, which is obviously not a complete json or dictionary.

What could be going wrong here? Is the server actually sending me a bad string, or does this have to do with the decoding of the response? How can I diagnose this?

Comment: I think problem is in your `stream=True` parameter. According http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow only the response headers have been downloaded. Try remove that parameter.

Comment: A good way to debug this is using wireshark and look into the actual requests/responses. Another way is setting up a proxy between the client and the server and let the proxy log all traffic. You could also configure nginx as reverse proxy in front of your server and log all requests. I think Andrej Kesely is right about the cause of the problem.

Comment: I didn't have this parameter initially (it's a debugging attempt). Unfortunately it does't affect the response.

Comment: Are you sure this error (as opposed to a different one) is reproducible without `stream = True`? If so, either the server is sending a bad response, or the server is sending a valid but complicated response that's confusing `requests` in some way (which is less likely, but not impossible). Try running the same request with `curl` in your shell to see what headers and data you get back.

Comment: Yes, it's the exact same error. I'm now trying to convert the request to curl using curlify, but the curlify requests is thousands of lines wrong (presumably as it it contains the attached file as bytes?), so it gets cut off.